# Print current month as calendar using current system date C++

Tags: c++, calendar, timestamp

First time poster so excuse me if I make any sort of mistake.

I am fairly new to the whole programming in C++ but I was wondering if it is possible to print out a calendar of a certain month (the current one) e.g. today it is June 2015 so I want to print out the monthly calendar of June 2015 in C++

If anyone has any suggestion how to make this possible that would be extremely helpful. I know how to post the current month with user input yet I want my program to look at the system date.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Give this a read.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8034469/c-how-to-get-the-actual-time-with-time-and-localtime). After that, the hard part is getting the correct days of the month.

Comment: You might start out  from [`std::chrono::timepoint`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/chrono/time_point).

Answer (score 0):

Use time(0) to get a time_t that is also somehow the number of seconds since xxxoopsxxxxx => epoch: Wed Dec 31 19:00:00 1969, so 1/1/1970

```
time_t linearTime = time(0);
```

Use localtime_r to convert the linearTime to

```
struct tm timeinfo = *localtime_r(&linearTime, &timeinfo);
```

Use struct tm to decode broken-down-time (in Linux, at /usr/include/time.h) and produce your calendar as you want.

Have fun.

Edit 2

Looked into chrono.  Figured out how to measure duration in us.

BUT, the following chrono stuff is suspiciously similar to previous stuff.

```
std::time_t t0 = std::time(nullptr);
std::tm* localtime(const std::time_t* t0); // std::tm has the fields you expect

// convenient to text
std::cout << std::asctime(std::localtime(&t0)); // prints the calendar info for 'now'
```

I suspect not much different at all.

edit 3

I have doubts.  I think the previous suspiciously familiar bit came from ctime, not chrono.  So I plan digging around in chrono some more.

Comment: Hmmmm, that's not really standard c++ ... I'd rather stick to `std::chrono`.

Comment: Agree .. I have not yet learned std::chrono.   I was being careful to not do the work for him ... This will be good practice for OP to learn both techniques.  Hope I find time, too ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot though. I am indeed not looking for the whole answer. Thank you both for the answers you have provided. I will look into it.